# (apple) Authentication failure! ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on, omniauth, apple-sso

I am trying to integrate Sign In with Apple using the omniauth-apple gem and documentation from omniauth requests to use POST in the link but when i do so, i get the following error

`(apple) Authentication failure! ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken, ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`

this is my code

```
= link_to 'Sign in via Apple', user_apple_omniauth_authorize_path, method: :post
```

But i do not get this error when I use `GET`. It works fine.

How do i make it work with POST?

Comment: Post needs to be in a form with a crsf token

Answer (score 0):

Use [`button_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to):

```rb
= button_to 'Sign in via Apple', user_apple_omniauth_authorize_path
```